# Why won't rectangle show on top window until a seemingly unrelated function is called?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I am trying to refresh on trying to draw directly on desktop window with GDI.

Nothing seemed to work until i saw an example that worked; but only after RegisterClassEx was called. I replaced RegisterClassEx with LoadIcon and it still works.

The code below only draws the square when LoadIcon is called(after the 3 second delay sleep).

Originally I thought it was just my MinGW, but I tested it in Visual Studio 2012, and it also doesn't draw the square until after the sleep.

Why is this happening and what can I do to make the drawing work without registering any window class/calling LoadIcon?

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 255));
    RECT rect = {0, 0, 100, 100};
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

    FillRect(hdc, &rect, hbr);
    Sleep(3000);
    LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I *think* the answer is that in order to use GDI, your application must have a message pump.  The top page of the [GDI documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx) refers to [Window Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381405(v=vs.85).aspx).  Parts of a GUI application with no message pump might still work, but not in a predictable way, e..g, the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Your answer seems to go in the right direction. It even works when I remove LoadIcon and put `CoInitialize(NULL);` at start of the block and `CoUninitialize();` at the end.

Comment: You could try calling `GdiFlush()`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that works. I was looking for that function. Kinda curious why it also works with CoInitialize(NULL) at start of program, even without CoUninitialize at the end(with no GdiFlush)... very odd.